# Best way to arrange custom post types by Attributes -> Order metabox value?

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, page-attributes

I have my front page setup to display a custom post type via:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

function my_get_posts( $query ) {

    if ( is_home() && false == $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] )         $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'jwf_portfolio', 'attachment' ) );
                $query->set( 'order', 'menu_order' );

    return $query; }
```

What's the most efficient way to have these ordered by the number value in the Order input in the Attributes metabox for each custom post? Currently I'm trying

```
<?php query_posts( $query_string . '&orderby=menu_order' ); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

on my `index.php` and that's not cutting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This did it:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

function my_get_posts( $query ) {

    if ( is_home() && false == $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'jwf_portfolio', 'attachment' ) );
                $query->set('orderby', 'menu_order');
                $query->set('order', 'ASC'); 

    return $query;
}
```

No need to mess with `index.php` now.

Comment: This does what you want it to, but it does a lot more. *Any* query will automatically order by 'menu_order'. Unless this is intended, you should make sure those $query->sets are wrapped up in the IF statement. Also, as a warning to people who would copy this solution: any query on the home page (which doesn't go through filters) will return only 'jwf_portfolio' or 'attachment'.

Comment: @Stephen Yes, this is intended, but good of you to point out that this is not a generic solution. +1